# How to compare dates in full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a dates stored in my database which I would like to compare with the elements of the calendar to change the background color of the days

```
{
  "success": true,
  "disponibilidad": [
    {
      "slot_date": "2017-06-08"
    },
    {
      "slot_date": "2017-06-09"
    },
    {
      "slot_date": "2017-06-10"
    },
    {
      "slot_date": "2017-06-11"
    },
    {
      "slot_date": "2017-06-12"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use jquery, and it works in a certain way, but the load time is too slow and too little optimum, in addition, if I change the month, a problem arises to color the days, my question is, is there a way to pass that array Of dates within dayRender?

the method that I had used

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    dayClick: function() {

        //alert("dia presionado");
        selectedDate = $(this).attr("data-date");

        alert($(this).attr("data-date"));
        //window.location.href="/reservation/"+selectedDate;
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', $(this).attr("data-date"));
    },

    dayRender: function(date, cell) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: '/getFaq',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var valores = [];
                valores[0] = "2017-06-27";
                valores[1] = "2017-06-28";
                for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                    if (date.format() == valores[i]) {
                        cell.css("background-color", "red");
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(response) {},
        });
}})
```

*Edit

I have embed the code using data properties, however, for some reason I can not use the variable within the dayrender, in the dayclick if it works

```
success: function(data)
        {
        myArray= new Array(data.disponibilidad.length);
        for(var i=0;i<data.disponibilidad.length;i++)
        {

            myArray[i]=data.disponibilidad[i].slot_date;
        }

        $( "body" ).data( "array",myArray);
        //for(var k=0; k< myArray.length;k++)
        //console.log($( "body" ).data( "array" )); 
        //console.log(myArray);


        }



$('#calendar_make_a_reservation').fullCalendar({
                height: 500,
                dayClick: function() {
                    $('#modal_appointment_time').modal('open');
                    /*
                    var array=$( "body" ).data( "array" );
         console.log(array);*/
                },
                dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                                var array=$( "body" ).data( "array" );
                                console.log(array);
            /*
            myArray.forEach(function (item) {
                if (date._d.getDate() == item.getDate() && date._d.getMonth() == item.getMonth()) 
                {
                    $(cell).toggleClass('selected');
                }
            });*/}

            })
```

In dayrender returns me "undefined"

Comment: rather than re-loading the array via ajax every time dayRender is called, download the array once when your page loads (or pre-embed it in the page if you can) as a global variable. Then in dayRender you can just check in the global variable. Also `date.format()` is unlikely to match `valores[i]` since it will include the time. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Thanks for replying Adyson, I have done what you told me, however, for some reason I can not use the variable within the dayrender, in the dayclick if it works,I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` is a [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) date object. You can compare adding parameters to the `format` method like:

```
date.format("YYYY-MM-DD") == valores[i]
```

Comment: a more proper way round would be to convert the string to a moment and then compare them as dates rather than a string comparison. But this misses the point raised by OP about performance and how to inject the array into dayRender.

Comment: I have embed the code using data properties, however, for some reason I can not use the variable within the dayrender, in the dayclick if it works, I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it, the problem with dayrender was due to synchronization, once the async is changed to false, everything works perfectly.

```
$.ajax({
        async:false,   
        cache:false, 
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',  
        url: 'getReservas',
        data:params,
        success: function(data)
        {
        myArray= new Array(data.disponibilidad.length);
        for(var i=0;i<data.disponibilidad.length;i++)
        {

            myArray[i]=data.disponibilidad[i].slot_date;
        }
        alert("segundo");
        var array=$( "body" ).data("array",myArray);
        //for(var k=0; k< myArray.length;k++)
        //console.log($( "body" ).data( "array" )); 
        //console.log(myArray);


        },

        error: function(data){
           alert("ha ocurrido un error") ;

        }
    });





$('#calendar_make_a_reservation').fullCalendar({
                height: 500,
                dayClick: function() {
                $('#modal_appointment_time').modal('open');
                 //console.log($( "body" ).data("array"));
                },
                dayRender: function (date, cell) {

               myArray.forEach(function (item) {



    if (date.format()==item) 
    {
        cell.css("background-color", "blue");
    }
       });

      }

      })
```

[image]

Comment: this might work for now but async:false is already deprecated in some browsers due to the poor user experience it creates (locking up the browser if the request takes longer than usual), so you can expect it to stop working at some time in the future.

Comment: I have seen that the problem is caused because the full calendar methods are loaded first than my jquery request, do you recommend me some alternative?

Comment: are you using a server side language? If so you could inject the json into the page using that instead of loading via ajax. Or, trigger creation of the calendar from the "success" method of your ajax request, so you can guarantee the data will load first.